# AppEngine Pipeline Yield - is this standard usage of the yield operator?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yield, pipeline

From the following page (http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/wiki/GettingStarted) I have seen the following code in an example of how to use the AppEngine pipeline:

```
class AddOne(pipeline.Pipeline):

  def run(self, number):
    return number + 1

class AddTwoAndLog(pipeline.Pipeline):

  def run(self, number):
    result = yield AddOne(number)
    final_result = yield AddOne(result)
    yield LogMessage('The value is: %d', final_result)  # Works
```

My question/confusion is about the yield statement on the right side of the "=". Is this standard python syntax/usage, or is this special case that is only allowed/used with the Pipeline model? What is happening here?

Comment: You might want to read up on generators as co-routines. http://antroy.blogspot.com/2007/04/python-coroutines.html I believe result is assigned to by the caller via send(...) But to answer our question, according to the above link it is standard syntax as of python2.5

Comment: Thanks Tom, at least I now know the terminology to look for, and have a starting to point to understanding what is going on here.

Comment: I found the following PDF presentation to be extremely clear and helpful for understanding coroutines: http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf

Comment: I think that the answer to my question is that in this case, the "yield" is simplye pausing execution until the value is available. In PEP 342, I found the following:

`Meanwhile, code that performs the I/O would simply do something like this:

data = (yield nonblocking_read(my_socket, nbytes))

in order to pause execution until the nonblocking_read() coroutine produced a value.`

Comment: NDB also uses this pattern extensively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning from a `yield` is standard as of Python 2.5. It enables coroutines.

See http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-342-new-generator-features

Comment: Thanks, I started using python 2 years ago, but hadn't come across coroutines yet.

Comment: It's rare to see it in the wild.